# How to call method that is in a class

Tags: c#, arrays, class, methods

Learning C# on my own (not homework).  I wrote a TotalDue method to calculate grand total of all customer balances due (from array).  Placed it within the Customer class so it would have access to the data.  I cannot figure out how to call this method in main.  How do I get the total to display?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Customer[] customers = new Customer[2];
        string customer;
        int id;
        double due;

        // GET DATA AND FILL ARRAY
        for (int x = 0; x < customers.Length; ++x)
        {
            GetData(out customer, out id, out due);
            customers[x] = new Customer(customer, id, due);
        }

        // SORT ARRAY - NEEDS ICOMPARABLE<Customer> - PART 1
        Array.Sort(customers);


        // PRINT ARRAY WITH TOSTRING() OVERRIDE
        for (int x = 0; x < customers.Length; ++x)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(customers[x].ToString());
        }

        //DON'T KNOW HOW TO CALL THE TOTAL DUE METHOD...


        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    class Customer : IComparable<Customer>  // SORT ARRAY - PART 2
    {
        private string CustomerName { get; set; }
        private int IdNumber { get; set; }
        private double BalanceDue { get; set; }

        // CONSTRUCTOR
        public Customer(string customer, int id, double due)
        {
            CustomerName = customer;
            IdNumber = id;
            BalanceDue = due;
        }

        //SORT THE ARRAY - PART 3
        public int CompareTo(Customer x)
        {
            return this.IdNumber.CompareTo(x.IdNumber);
        }

        // OVERRIDE TOSTRING TO INCLUDE ALL INFO + TOTAL
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return ("\nCustomer: " + CustomerName + "\nID Number: " + IdNumber + "\nBalance Due: " + BalanceDue.ToString("C2"));
        }

        // TOTAL DUE FOR ALL CUSTOMERS
        static void TotalDue(Customer [] customers)
        {
            double Total = 0;

            for (int x = 0; x < customers.Length; ++x)
                Total += customers[x].BalanceDue;

            Console.WriteLine("Total Amount Due:  {0}", Total.ToString("C2"));
        }
    }

    // GET DATA METHOD
    static void GetData(out string customer, out int id, out double due)
    {
        Console.Write("Please enter Customer Name:  ");
        customer = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Please enter ID Number:  ");
        int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out id);
        Console.Write("Please enter Balance Due:  $");
        double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out due);
    }

}
```

Comment: `Customer.TotalDue(customers);`

Comment: `Customer` class is `private` since the access modifier is not defined. Change to `public class` or `internal class` to allow it to be seen.

Comment: @JLT, your method doesn't have any access specifier, so it is treated as private, Make it `public`

Comment: @DavidHaney The `Main` method is in the same outer class as `Customer`, so even though the class is private, it's still in scope where he wants to call it.

Comment: Why are you using so many `out` parameters?

Comment: @Servy I believe you're correct. The method itself has the `private` access modifier. Whoops.

Comment: @outis nihil I used out parameters as per the assignment in the book.

Answer (score 2):

Make `TotalDue` method public as the default access modifier in C# is private and then try this.

```
class Customer : IComparable<Customer>  // SORT ARRAY - PART 2
{
     public static void TotalDue(Customer [] customers)
     {
        double Total = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < customers.Length; ++x)
            Total += customers[x].BalanceDue;

        Console.WriteLine("Total Amount Due:  {0}", Total.ToString("C2"));
     }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // ...........
    //............
     Customer.TotalDue(customers);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The default access modifier in C# is `private`. Since your `TotalDue` method does not specify anything else, it is `private`. You can change this to `public` and call it from your `Main`.

Answer (score 0):

Add public access modifier with your static method and call it with name of class or remove the static keyword and make it instance and call class method.

Answer (score -1):

make your Customer class method (TotalDue) Public and NOT static...

Comment: In his case `static` is correct. It's not referencing any instance members.